# Ionic - Angular list detail linking

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, state, factory, controllers

I'm trying to make a Master-Detail module, but is not working. When I tap on the link that should go to the detail page, nothing happens, and in the console doesn't show any error. I'm working over a template created by Ionic Creator.

These are my controllers:

```
 .controller('administraciNCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','obtenerPerfiles', function ($scope, $stateParams,obtenerPerfiles) {

    var initView = function(){
        $scope.perfiles = obtenerPerfiles.query();
        //console.log('Scope es:',$scope);
    }

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded',function(){
        initView();
    });
}])
    .controller('profesionalDetailCtrl', function ($scope, perfil) {
 var initView = function(perfil){
        $scope.perfil = perfil;
        //console.log('Scope es:',$scope);
    }

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded',function(){
        initView();
    });

})
```

This is the factory:

```
.factory('obtenerPerfiles', function($resource){
    var getProfile = {};

    getProfile.getPerfil = function(nombrePerfil){
       /*I will use nombrePerfil later, first I wanna test it works*/
        var datos;
        datos = {"nombre": "yuyu","direccion":"carrera 11","perfil":"Administradorcita"};
        return datos;
    };

    return $resource('bd/administracion.json', {}, { query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}}); 
});
```

This is the state:

```
 .state('cONSTRYELO2.administraciN', {
    url: '/page7',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/administraciN.html',
        controller: 'administraciNCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('cONSTRYELO2.profesionalDetail', {
    url: '/perfilDetalle/:nombrePerfil',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/profesionalDetail.html',
        controller: 'profesionalDetailCtrl',
        resolve:{
            perfil: function($stateParams,obtenerPerfiles){
               return obtenerPerfiles.getPerfil($stateParams.nombrePerfil);
            }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

And finally this is the HTML:

```
  <ion-item class="item-icon-left item-icon-right" id="administraciN-list-item47" ui-sref="cONSTRYELO2.profesionalDetail({nombrePerfil:'{{perfil.nombre}}'})">
        <i class="icon ion-android-globe"></i>3km
        <span class="item-note">Ver más</span>
        <i class="icon ion-android-add-circle"></i>
  </ion-item>
```